# How can I get the second span using BeautifulSoup in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to get the second span value in this div and others like it (shown below)

```
<div class="C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)">
    <span>VALUE 1</span>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="Mx(4px)">•</i>
    <span>TRYING TO GET THIS</span>
</div>
```

I've tried looking at similar stack posts, but I still couldn't figure out how to fix this.
Here's my current code:

```
time = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)'})
    for i in time:
        print(i.text) #this prints VALUE 1 x amount of times (there are multiple divs)
```

I've tried things like i.span, i.contents, i.children, etc.
I'd really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Have you consulted the BeatifulSoup docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to get the value you want.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html='''
<div class="C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)">
    <span>VALUE 1</span>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="Mx(4px)">•</i>
    <span>TRYING TO GET THIS</span>
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
divs = doc.getElementsByClass('C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)')
for div in divs:
  value = div.getElementByTag('span',start='</span>') # Use start to skip the first
  print (value)
  value = div.getElementByTag('span',before='<span>',end=len(div.html)) # Locate the last
  print (value)
  value = div.i.next # Use <i> to locate
  print (value)
  value = div.spans[-1]
  print (value)
  print (value.text)
```

Result:

```
{'tag': 'span', 'html': 'TRYING TO GET THIS'}
{'tag': 'span', 'html': 'TRYING TO GET THIS'}
{'tag': 'span', 'html': 'TRYING TO GET THIS'}
{'tag': 'span', 'html': 'TRYING TO GET THIS'}
TRYING TO GET THIS
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
from io import StringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = """<div class="C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)">
    <span>VALUE 1</span>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="Mx(4px)">•</i>
    <span>TRYING TO GET THIS</span>
</div>
<div class="another class">
    <span>VALUE 1</span>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="Mx(4px)">•</i>
    <span>TRYING TO GET THIS</span>
</div>"""

soup = bs(StringIO(data))
spans = soup.select('div[class="C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)"] > span')
print(spans[1].text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically had it, you just need to get at the second span in each the div (find_next):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)'})
for div in divs:
    # want the second span in the div
    span = div.find_next('span').find_next('span')
    print(span.string)
```

Comment: Is there something cleaner like “doc.find_last(‘span’)”

Comment: span = div.find_all('span').pop()

Answer (score 0):

```
div= soup.find_all('div',class_='C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)')
[x.get_text() for x in div[0].find_all('span')]

#op

Out[17]:
['VALUE 1', 'TRYING TO GET THIS']
```